# round tick marks dynamically with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I have the following dataframe:

```
rExp <- read.table(text='     samples variable value
UT            F201/203    0.00255836649706595
siCTL         F201/203    0.00911222024608249
siF201/203    F201/203    0.00473993831657716
UT            F203        0.0108815320248598
siCTL         F203        0.0224404694390467
siF201/203    F203        0.0115692755110973
UT            F203/206    0.00392331892967821
siCTL         F203/206    0.010474094476624
siF201/203    F203/206    0.00494613385979193',   header=TRUE)
```

I create a grouped bar plot using the following code:

```
p_rEx<- ggplot (data=rExp, aes(x=samples, y=value)) + scale_x_discrete(limits=samples)
p_rEx<- p_rEx + geom_bar (aes(fill = variable),stat = "identity", position = "dodge", colour='black')
p_rEx<- p_rEx + labs(y="relative expression", x='')
p_rEx<- p_rEx + guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL))
p_rEx<- p_rEx + scale_fill_manual(values=gray.colors(3, start = 0.3, end = 0.9, gamma = 2.2, alpha = NULL))
p_rEx
```

The result is the following plot:

[image]

My problem with this is, that the tick marks are very weird numbers.
I would like them to be more "round", e.g. 0.01 instead of 0.010474094476624

The y axis needs to stay continuous though, as y values could be anywhere between 10 and 1*10^-10.

I tried something like  `+ scale_y_continuous(breaks= pretty_breaks())`, but gave me an error (`Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`)

Is there a way to fix this?
Thank you!

Edit:
I do not think this is the duplicate of this question:
[How do I change the number of decimal places on axis labels in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722202/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-decimal-places-on-axis-labels-in-ggplot2)

Here, I ask for a dynamic version, that works for all y values. so a dynamic adjustment of the decimal places

Comment: The solution offered in the question that was marked as duplicate, is not applicable.

Comment: I don't get the same plot as your with your sample data above. Are you sure this is correct? It looks like the class if your value column might be a factor rather than numeric. Make sure your [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) is actually reproducible.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick. I noticed something curious: It seems that when I enter my data, to post it here, it get's rounded to the 9th digit. This didn't happen in my original data (you can see I put in more digits than are displayed when you print the rExp DF. Indeed, my values in my original data seem to be factors, when I change it to numeric, the tick marks are prettier. however, I slightly round my data....

Comment: @Sotos I don't think the duplicate you've linked to is appropriate. The problem seems to be that the data are a factor rather than numeric.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've just imprted your values are a factor variable rather than numeric. Therefor the problem really is with your data import and not ggplot. But you can maybe fix it with

```
ggplot(data=rExp, aes(x=samples, y=as.numeric(as.character(value))))
```

Comment: Thank you.
I already implemented this after you posted your comment and it solved the problem.
Cheers mate!