# Percentage Label for R without decimals

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the process of creating a boxplot, I have percentages on the y-axis. However it shows up, for example, as `20.0%` and I would prefer `20%`. Does anybody know how to correct for this?

```
box<-ggplot(boxy,aes(x=type,y=value))+
    geom_boxplot()+
    scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)+ #where I am trying to fix the axis
    theme()
)
```

The answer found here: [How do I change the number of decimal places on axis labels in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722202/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-decimal-places-on-axis-labels-in-ggplot2) does not make sense to me because of the notation of the function itself. Also, it is less intuitive than declaring the number of decimals in the scale part of `ggplot`

Data:

```
type<-c(rep("One",10),rep("Two",10))
value<-c(91,15,55,7,2,19,72,8,52,61,93,48,20,44,33,84,80,88,26,23)
boxy<-data.frame(type,value)
```

Comment: Thank you to those above. Although @SaurabhChauhan 's answer does not work, it was more of what I was looking for.

Comment: @Jimbou: Agree with you. I misunderstood it. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: I think one of the answers in the linked-to post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53362011) is the best solution, namely `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case you can simply paste the `"%"`

```
ggplot(boxy,aes(x=type,y=value))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x) paste0(x,"%"))
```

[image]

As you can read here `?scale_y_continuous` you can provide a function which "takes the breaks as input and returns labels as output". Input breaks (`x`), add `"%"`, output labels.

Comment: This works. But can you explain the notation. I understand `pate0` but how does the `function(x)` immediatly know to refer to the `paste0`. Although it may be trivial to you, it is not something that is immediatly clear.