# Deleting decimals in percentages axis - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a plot where I need to delete the decimals from the percentage numbers. The data is already rounded (two decimals), an example of the data:

```
> head(df$X)
[1] 0.05 0.28 0.08 0.19 0.33
```

And then I plot it, using `scale_x_continuous()` to transform it to percentage format, but as you can see in the image below they still have one decimal and I need those numbers without decimals.

[image: Output]

This is the code for the graph:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=df$X, y=DF$Y)) + 
    geom_point(
        colour="red",
        size=5
        ) + 
  geom_text(label=df$Label, vjust=-2, family="sans", fontface="bold") +
  labs(x="X", y="Y") + xlim(-1,1) + ylim(-1,1) + scale_x_continuous(labels=scales::percent) + scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent)
```

The closest answer I have found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52098127/percentage-label-for-r-without-decimals), but I don't need to paste the "%" symbol as I already have it.

Comment: Side note: Don't use `data$col` inside `aes()`. It will still work for simple plots, but it will cause problems with many of ggplot's advanced features. Just do `ggplot(df, aes(x = X, y = Y))`. And you should probably put the `label` inside `aes` too: `geom_text(aes(label = Label), ...)`

Comment: @Gregor `scales::percent` doesn't take a digits argument, but it *does* take an accuracy argument. It's formatted differently, though; worth looking at the examples in the docs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scales::percent` has an `accuracy` argument that you can modify. This should give you what you want:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(
    colour="red",
    size=5
  ) + 
  labs(x="X", y="Y") + 
  xlim(-1,1) + 
  ylim(-1,1) + 
  scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) scales::percent(x, accuracy = 1)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) scales::percent(x, accuracy = 1))
```