# ggplot2 log scale labels with different digits

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to display labels as

```
0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100
```

instead of

```
0.01, 0.10, 1.00, 10.00, 100.00
```

i.e., truncating trailing zeros after the decimal?

```r
x <- c(0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100)
scales::demo_log10(x)
scales::demo_log10(x, labels = scales::label_number())
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the number of decimal places on axis labels in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722202/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-decimal-places-on-axis-labels-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `label_number()` function forwards the `...` argument to the `format()` function. This mean that you use its `drop0trailing` argument to control whether 0s are printed after the decimal mark.

```
library(scales)
demo_log10(
  c(0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100),
  labels = label_number(drop0trailing = TRUE)
)
#> scale_x_log10(labels = label_number(drop0trailing = TRUE))
```